# HttpClient performance issues when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have the code below. Running it locally I get the response back from the API in under 1 second.

When I deploy it to a server, it's taking anywhere between 3 and 10 minutes to get the response!

I've deployed to 3 different servers with the same result. Any idea what might be wrong?

Below is my code:

```
string response = string.Empty;
try
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var responseMessage = client.PostAsync("https://myapi/createshorturl", content).Result;
        response = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateShortUrlResponse>(response);
    }
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: The server is on dial-up, the server is behind a slow proxy, and so on. We can't say anything about this, the code is irrelevant.

Comment: phuzi, to me that comment would be an "answer."  Otherwise easily overlooked.

Comment: Don't use `.Result` to block on an async operation. That, along with any other inefficient code could be enough to cause a *lot* of performance issues. In a desktop app that would block the UI thread. In an ASP.NET app that would waste threads doing nothing

Comment: Seems to me you need a generous helping of how to use `HttpClient` and how Tasks work in general.

Comment: `catch (Exception x)
{
    return null;}` ??? Are you sure you aren't receiving a *lot* of exceptions that are simply covered up?

Comment: @CodeCaster what do you mean the server is on dial up, how would you know that without being the op?

Comment: @johnny5 my comment means to represent the start of a list of possible causes. There's simply too many.

Comment: Also, yeah, everyone is using HttpClient wrong, but that either works, or deadlocks, or runs into socket exhaustion after a lot of calls. It doesn't introduce random delays of 3 to 10 minutes. Don't post boilerplate answers if the problem is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you're using HttpClient wrong. Take a look at the following articles before continuing to use it:

- [You're Using HttpClient Wrong And It Is Destabilizing Your Software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)
- [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

TL;DR:

- HttpClient holds on to the underlying socket far longer than you think.
- Reuse HttpClient, do not create a new one for every request.
- Use IHttpClientFactory
- Don't `.Result`

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` instances should be reused, that should be your first stop to making changes here. Secondly, don't **ever** do `Task.Result` if you can avoid it. It is a synchronous call likely falling behind under load.

```
class Something
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<CreateShortUrlResponse> GetResponseAsync()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            {
                var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("https://myapi/createshorturl", content);
                response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateShortUrlResponse>(response);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            //you should log something here, rather than silently returning null. Or let it propagate up to where it can be handled.
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```